# Export multiple tables in separate pages in modelsummary

Tags: r, modelsummary

The `modelsummary` package allows to export summary tables of models do word documents. However, I want to use export multiple tables on different pages. However, when I repeat modelsummary with my new models and choose the same output, the tables just get overwritten. I am wondering, if it is possible?

```
modelsummary(models1, 
             output = "table.docx")

modelsummary(models2, 
             output = "table.docx")
```

Comment: I don’t understand why you aren’t giving the output names as different values.

Comment: Because I want to have them in one document.

Answer (score 3):

`modelsummary` can combine a list of models into one table.

To add a separate table for every model summary, you can use package {officer} like this:

```
library(modelsummary)
library(officer)
```

- use a *named* model list (the names will be used for temporary file names later on):

```
the_models <- list(
  m1 = lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris),
  m2 = lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species, iris)
)
```

- create an empty doc representation:

```
all_tables_doc <- read_docx()
```

- save one (temporary) docx file per model summary,
  and add these files to the main document's representation (here: `all_tables_doc`):

```
names(the_models) |>
  Map(f = \(name){
    file_name <- file.path(tempdir(), paste0(name,'.docx'))
    modelsummary(the_models[[name]], file_name)
    all_tables_doc <- all_tables_doc |>
      body_add_docx(file_name)
    name
  })
```

(In above pipe, you can [add further elements](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/reference/index.html#add-content-to-word-documents) like page preaks or  captions per table.)

- save result as docx:

```
print(all_tables_doc, 'all_tables.docx')
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't had time to check this code out yet, but will get back to you! :)